# Как создать границы камере в Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создаю игру, мне надо чтобы камера двигалась плавно за персонажем и не выходила за пределы уровня.
Нашёл видосик по созданию плавный камеры:

https://youtu.be/qHFsgJVyO2Q?t=309

Переписал и попробовал сделать границе камере сам

(Да я знаю что есть Cinemachine, но мне надо именно кодингом)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform player;
    private Vector3 pos;

    public float borderUp;
    public float borderDown;
    public float borderLeft;
    public float borderRight;

    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        pos = player.position;
        pos.z = -10;

        if ((pos.y < borderUp && pos.y > borderDown) && (pos.x < borderLeft && pos.x > borderRight))
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pos, Time.deltaTime);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Но мой код не работает

Comment: Мне надо кодом потому что учавствую в соревновании. И условие без инета и ассетов

Comment: Я здесь вижу техзадание для фриланса. Сколько даешь?) Если нет, то исправляй вопрос - в нем должны быть видны попытки хоть что-то сделать самому.

Comment: Вот переделал. Химичил, но нечего не получилось. Вот мой самый нормальный вариант

Comment: логируй все значения через Debug.Log() и разберись что не так с каким именно значением и исправь код

Comment: логировать pos или другое

Comment: Непонятно что логировать.

Comment: По логике проекта всё должно работать

Comment: Типо: Если позиция камеры по x < -10 но x > 10 то камера двигается за игроком

Comment: Но так не работает. А ты просто сказал примерно так "Ну это просто всё проверь и переделай код" и как тут понять где у меня ошибка???

Comment: в смысле непонятно что логировать? Все переменные которые влияют на логику работы камеры (player.position и все бордеры). А что еще логировать?

Comment: камера не хочет двигаться в этих пределах